# Why is my question off-topic?

Tags: support, scope, specific-question

The question [In what sense did Trump put a notch on his belt?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79075/in-what-sense-did-trump-put-a-notch-on-his-belt) was originally posted on ELU (not by me) with a language connotation, then I decided to post it here because I wondered if the expression “a notch on his belt” actually had a political connotation given the context and the people involved.

I am not American and I am not fully aware of possible implications or hidden meaning that the expression, as said by Trump’s lawyers in that context,  may possibly suggest.
Where else could I ask?

Answer (score 3):

Putting a notch on your belt has nothing to do with politics and is just a general phrase that can be used in many places and isn't political in nature.

As a note this question has been asked and answered on English Language & Usage and cross posting questions on multiple sites is discouraged

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605638/what-does-put-a-notch-on-his-belt-mean-is-it-a-common-expression/605643#605643

Comment: I don’t see your  point, all terms are not political per se, it depends on context, as in this case. And the context is “very” political as far as I understand .

Comment: @user66974 It is a phrase that has a meaning that has nothing to do with politics, just because a term/phrase is used about a political figure doesn't mean it suddenly has anything to do with politics.

Comment: Mmmmm..I doubt that Trump’s lawyers publicly said something politically irrelevant on that occasion. But I am wrong, of course.

Comment: Btw, I didn’t cross post. On ELU the question, asked by a different user, had a language connotation and was about the expression itself. That just made me think about its meaning in context..which is a political context.

Comment: @user66974 Again, just because something is said by a political figure, someone connected to a political figure or about a political figure doesn't mean that it is related to politics in anyway. And even if you didn't post it yourself cross posting questions between sites is still discouraged.

Comment: Ok, I see your point, but I totally disagree!!! BTW again, it is not cross posting. They are different questions though the subject is the same.